# Why am I getting this output from printing the contents of an array with only 17 bytes?

Tags: c, cs50

I am working through CS50 on edX and have reached the problem where you have to do a checksum for credit card numbers.I am new to programming and even newer to C.

I am collecting the digits in arrays so I can manipulate them.
I have collected every other digit from the original number and multiplied this by two.

When I try to print this collection I get the digits I want initially but then a dash and whole load of other numbers - I have no idea where these are coming from?

```
// establishing another array to collect the doubled digits of every other digit from the first array
int doubledDigs[16];
int k = 0;
// building that array, ensuring to split any multi digit products and add them idnividually
for (int i = 0; i<= 15; i += 2, k++)
{
   int a = collector[i] * 2;
   if (a > 9)
   {
       for (int c=0; c < 2; c++, k++)
       {
           int b = a % 10;
           doubledDigs[k] = b;
           a = floor(a / 10);
       }
   }
   doubledDigs[k] = a;
}
// print doubledDigs to check it is working
for (int i = 0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    int b = doubledDigs[i];
    printf ("%i", b);
}
printf ("\n");

//add all the doubled digits together
int doubledProduct = 0;
for (int i=0; i <= 15; i++)
{
    doubledProduct += doubledDigs[i];
}
//print product to check
printf("%i\n", doubledProduct);
```

So if input 1234567890123 as my card number I get 62810410010620-74895702432659
-748924334
as an output.The first 14 digits are correct and the ones that I want - but where are all these other numbers coming from?

Comment: Aside: in `a = floor(a / 10);` do your realise that `a / 10` is an *integer* division? So there is never any fractional part to discard.

Comment: It is perverse to use *two* magic numbers on the same array. Firstly `int doubledDigs[16];` followed by `i <= 15;` where it would be clearer as `i < 16`. But it is better to `#define` a length, or declare a `const` and derive everything from that.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this output because of one of two things: either you're accessing your `collector` array out of its bounds, or you're failing to initialize the last few members of that array, resulting in garbage data being accessed.

Your algorithm assumes that `collector` and `doubledDigs` have the same number of members, but since your code doesn't include the part where you declare that array, it's unclear if that is true or not.

Assuming they are the same size, if you're filling `collector` with the input "1234567890123", then you're leaving 3 uninitialized members. In C, if you do not explicitly set the value of a variable or array member, its initial value is equal to whatever happens to be in memory at that particular location. For a signed `int`, that can be anywhere between 2,147,483,647 and -2,147,483,648.

To guard against this, the first thing you may want to do is zero-initialize your array using `int collector[16] = {0};`.

That only fixes things in the case that `collector` and `doubledDigs` are supposed to be the same size. If it's intended that `collector` has 14 members and `doubledDigs` has 16, for instance, you will have to revisit your loop logic. In that example, in the last 2 iterations of the loop, you will attempt access the 15th and 16th members of `collector`, which don't exist. C will not stop you from doing this, but the result is undefined behavior at best.